# What Data Persistence method to use?

Tags: android, mysql, jpa, amazon-ec2, jax-rs

I am making an android app which will retrieve some information from a remote MySQL database. I will be using restful java web service using JAX-RS which will interact with MySQL DB to retrieve data from tables. I am aware that for interacting with an underlying database, some implementation of JPA can be used. But since I only need to retrieve data from DB and not to insert any new data using my android app (as a client).

So do I really need to implement JPA? 
If not, how should I make my java web service fetch data from MySQL database?

My database is installed on Amazon ec2-instance where I am running apache tomcat 7. What will be the best approach? If you can refer me to some good tutorials, please do.

Comment: also, take a look [jcabi-jdbc](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-jdbc/), a fluent interface to a relational database, via JDBC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to implement JPA for this solution if it's a fairly small set of data you require from your description.  You could just build a RESTful web service that just does simple JDBC queries to the database whenever it's called.

REST request comes in - gets interrogated by the web service - web service fetches data - returns XML / JSON response from Tomcat.  Also - as you're using Tomcat and not an application server, if you did want to go down the JPA route I would recommend Hibernate as you wouldn't be able to use EJB without an application server such as JBoss.  Even then, unless it was a large system just a Tomcat instance running some JDBC should work fine, especially in EC2.

Answer (score 2):

You're exactly one afternoon away from a wonderfully simple app that contains zero marshaling code and no added libraries... if you chose the right parts.

There seems to be a pervasive thought that if an application is "too small" it should avoid certain technologies.  The fact is even these small apps would be **far smaller** if they *did* use the right technologies.

I'd recommend using JAX-RS and JPA and using the EE version of Tomcat ([TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org)).

I work on TomEE, but reading your requirements -- especially the EC2 part -- I just have to mention it.  TomEE is basically Tomcat with additional libraries added and Java EE 6 Web Profile [certified on EC2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/community/tomee-jee6-tested-config-512329.html) (t1.micros and higher).  It's rather tiny and can pass TCK with just the default memory settings.  That means even with a small t1.micro which has 613MB memory, the server takes up only small percentage of that.

Here is a JAX-RS application that can read/write `Movie` objects from a database.  It consists of two java files and one xml file.  No added libraries.

### Movie.java

Our `Movie` object can represent both the JSON data *and* the database data, so we don't need to do any marshaling to/from JSON or to/from the database.  All this is handled for us.

```
package org.stackoverflow;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "movie")
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String director;
    private String title;
    private int year;

    public Movie() {
    }

    public Movie(String director, String title, int year) {
        this.setDirector(director);
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setYear(year);
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDirector() {
        return director;
    }

    public void setDirector(String director) {
        this.director = director;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

### Movies.java

Here we have a simple RESTful service that can `GET` and `POST` movies.

```
package org.stackoverflow;

import javax.ejb.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;

@Path("/rest/movies")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Singleton
@Lock(LockType.READ)
public class Movies {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Movie getMovie(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        return entityManager.find(Movie.class, id);
    }

    @POST
    public void addMovie(Movie movie) {
        entityManager.persist(movie);
    }
}
```

### persistence.xml

To drive this, we just need a simple `WEB-INF/persistence.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

  <persistence-unit name="unit">
    <jta-data-source>movieDatabase</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

A fun thing to note about the above is the `openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings` property which will cause the JPA provider (OpenJPA in this case) to create all the database tables for us if they don't exist.

### Done

Believe it or not, that's it.  This app works.  Let's take a look at the contents of the war file so we can fully see all that is and is not in the war.

```
demo.war
demo.war/META-INF
demo.war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
demo.war/WEB-INF
demo.war/WEB-INF/classes
demo.war/WEB-INF/classes/org
demo.war/WEB-INF/classes/org/stackoverflow
demo.war/WEB-INF/classes/org/stackoverflow/Movie.class
demo.war/WEB-INF/classes/org/stackoverflow/Movies.class
demo.war/WEB-INF/lib
demo.war/WEB-INF/persistence.xml
```

Basically 3 files, `Movies.class`, `Movie.class`, and `persistence.xml`

### Test Drive

We'll use `curl` as it's easy.  We'll create a small file called `mymovie.txt` with the following contents:

```
{
    "movie":{
       "director":"David Dobkin",
       "title":"Wedding Crashers",
       "year":2005
    }
 }
```

Then we can add that movie by posting it to the server:

```
$ curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "@mymovie.txt" http://localhost:8080/demo/rest/movies
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /demo/rest/movies HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 106
> 
* upload completely sent off: 106 out of 106 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Date: Mon, 03 Dec 2012 21:12:23 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Now we can get the movie easily with a simple command:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/demo/rest/movies/1
{"movie":[{"director":"David Dobkin","id":1,"title":"Wedding Crashers","year":2005}]}
```

Comment: I have installed tomcat 7 on my ec2 instance. Can you guide me on how to install tommy on ec2.

Comment: You should just need to unpack the zip or tar.gz file.  How did you install Tomcat on EC2?

Comment: I installed using the usual command yum install service tomcat7. I don't know the location where i need to unpack the tar.gz of tomee. I have extracted it to /opt

Comment: It isn't yet available via yum, but we can definitely add that.  /opt/ is good.  Everything should be the same -- you just start/stop via the `tomcat.home/bin/starup.sh` and `tomcat.home/bin/shutdown.sh`.  I'm going to have to see if I can find the source to the yum package (not even sure who creates it)